# Not able to printout string variable from trycatch block on servlet http response

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, ejb

I am new to J2EE application and trying to display records from database  after searching it by the student id which is also my primary key.   jdbc/studentDB  is my JNDI name.
Is MY syntax  @Resource(name="jdbc/studentDB") in studentdao.java enough for the connection?If yes,Is the problem with method executeFetchQuery(int id)?
Where I am going wrong please help.

```
    //search.java(servlet)

    ResultSet rs = ***studentDao.executeFetchQuery(v);***
    String fName = null; 
    try{
          fName = rs.getString("firstname");
        while(rs.next()){ 

    fName = rs.getString("firstname");


    }
    }catch (Exception ex){
      System.out.println("error: "+ex);
            }

        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet getdata</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("fname: "+ fName);
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
```

//studentdao.java

```
 //required imports
 @Stateless
 public class StudentDao implements StudentDaoLocal {
 @Resource(name="jdbc/studentDB")
 private DataSource datasource;


@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public void addStudent(Student student) {
    em.persist(student);
}

@Override
public void editStudent(Student student) {
    em.merge(student);
}

@Override
public void deleteStudent(int studentId) {
    em.remove(getStudent(studentId));
}

@Override
public Student getStudent(int studentId) {
    return em.find(Student.class, studentId);
}

@Override
public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
    return em.createNamedQuery("Student.getAll").getResultList();
}

/**
 *
 * @param id
 * @return
 */
@Override
***public  ResultSet executeFetchQuery(int id){***
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{ 
       Connection conn = datasource.getConnection();
       String sql = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE STUDENTID = '" + id +"'";
       rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
       conn.close();
   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.err.println(e.getMessage());
   }
  return rs;
  }
```

// output for a id in database

fname :null

Answer (score 0):

<del>The following always will cause an exception because you are calling rs.getString() before rs.next()</del>

<del>try{
        fName = rs.getString("firstname");
        while(rs.next()){ 
            fName = rs.getString("firstname");
        }
}</del>



<del>Remove the first `fName = rs.getString("firstname");` The the try block will be like</del>



<del>try{
        while(rs.next()){ 
            fName = rs.getString("firstname");
        }
}</del>

**Update**

In `StudentDao.executeFetchQuery(int)` you are returning an `ResultSet` but the `Connection` used to get the `ResultSet` is closed so the `ResultSet` will also be closed.

This is not correct way to do. Return the `firstname` from `StudentDao.executeFetchQuery(int)` so it should be.

```
public String executeFetchQuery(int id){
  String firstname = null;
  try{ 
    Connection conn = datasource.getConnection();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE STUDENTID = '" + id +"'";
    rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
    if(rs.next()){
      firstName = rs.getString("firstname");
    }
    conn.close();
  }catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
  }
  return firstname;
}
```

And in `search.java`

```
String fname = studentDao.executeFetchQuery(v);
```

Comment: ,Hi,I tried removing [fName = rs.getString("firstname");],but the output still remains same.Is the problem in ResultSet executeFetchQuery(int id) method in studentdao.java.The variable fName in search.java(servlet) is passesd out of try catch block properly.ryt?? please help

Comment: fName: null,(why the value is not being changed after going through tryCatch block)

Comment: Check is there any exceptions